# How to querying from two list of objects in jsonata?

Tags: json, jsonata

I am trying to query a json through Jsonata but I dont know how to do it.

This is what I have:

```
{
  "first-array": [
    {
      "param1": {
        "status": "SUCCESS"
      }
    },
    {
      "param2": {
        "status": "FAILURE"
      }
    },
    {
      "param3": {
        "status": "SUCCESS"
      }
    }
  ],
  "second-array": [
    {
      "param1": {
        "attribute1": "1",
        "attribute2": "2"
      }
    },
    {
      "param2": {
        "attribute3": "3",
        "attribute4": "4"
      }
    },
    {
      "param3": {
        "attribute5": "5",
        "attribute6": "6"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

This is what I want. filter by SUCCESS status and retrieve only the attributes. For instance:

```
[
  {
    "param1": {
      "attribute1": "1",
      "attribute2": "2"
    }
  },
  {
    "param3": {
      "attribute5": "5",
      "attribute6": "6"
    }
  }
]
```

I have tried several things during this week, but I did not reach any way to proceed.
Trying with merge functions, overwrite the entire value, instead of append.
Trying to filter with something like first-array.*[status = "SUCCESS"] deletes the key where is the content.

Thank you.
BR,

Answer (score 1):

I think you can utilize `$each` function to convert your `first-array` into a utilizable map for filtering your `second-array`, something like this: https://stedi.link/qEzDJFm

Answer (score 0):

Based on your idea to use something like `first-array.*[status = "SUCCESS"]` here is a solution that should have linear complexity.

```
(
  $successes := $.`first-array`[*.status = "SUCCESS"] ~> $keys();
  $attributes := $.`second-array` ~> $filter(function($v) { $v ~> $keys() in $successes });
  [$attributes[]]
)
```

https://stedi.link/VmFVNe0

**EDIT**

This solution offers the benefit that duplicate entries in `first-array` do not change the result. See https://stedi.link/sn3OUW5 where `{ "param1": { "status": "SUCCESS" } }` exists twice.